# Does my Factory object introduces a global state?

Tags: dependency-injection, factory, global

So, here's the deal. I've managed to make a framework without using globals or static classes/functions.

I am using a form of dependency injection using a Factory. Since the framework will be used for various things, I'm creating a more generic Factory that will build your class, with it's dependencies recursively.

The thing is, to conserve memory, each time an object gets instantiated, the Factory stores a reference to it, so if another object has a dependency to that object, the Factory will only need to return the reference. That way we don't need to instantiate the same object twice.

This means, in lots of classes, we will have many different references to the same object. For example, if I declare Blog_model, Blog_controller, Blog_view, Form_validation to require the Config object, each of them will be instantiated with a reference to the same Config object, albeit with injection.

I'm not familiar with unit testing or any kind of automatic testing. I've just discovered that using globals and statics are bad (which is why I'm rewriting the framework I use). What I want to ask is, does this introduce a global state? Does it hinders testing in any way?

---- Update ------

It's an MVC framework written in PHP.

Comment: 1) Talking about re-inventing the wheel. 2) You are thinking too much. 3) It is not so much about removing globals, but to do proper compartmentalization. I suggest you read about cohesion and coupling, but **read them very well, once, and then again to make sure you truly get it**.

Comment: @luis.espinal - I know I don't know a lot, I just wanted to build a simple MVC framework that can be unit tested. I'm going to dig on cohesion, coupling, and compartmentalization.

Comment: not knowing it's ok, since we all start from zero. What I'm trying to say is that you need to work diligently on the basics before attempting more challenging work. By all means experiment, but you won't get far without really delving into the basics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I read this question, you have essentially created a **Dependency Injection Container** that only supports a single lifestyle.

Closely related to DI is the concept of **lifetime management**. If we ask for an instance of a specific type multiple times, do we get the same reference every time, or do we get a fresh instance each time?

If we get the same instance every time we call it the **Singleton lifestyle** - not to be confused with the Singleton design pattern.

If we get a new instance each time we call it the **Transient lifestyle**.

There are also other types of lifestyles, such as scoped, pooled, etc. but the above two are the most basic lifestyles.

It sounds to me that your DI container only supports the Singleton lifestyle. This **isn't the same as Global state**, but state *is* shared within a single instance of the container. However, if you throw away the container instance, your also throw away the shared state, so it's much easier to get rid of than global state.

Comment: The singleton is an abomination of a global state, and one of the most abused anti-pattern. So, how is the global state different from the single instance of his class? He can also remove the global state without much hassle (the same way he can remove his container)

Comment: @Mark Seemann - thanks for the detailed answer! So it's a DIC with singleton lifestyle management. Is it still a Factory? I'm assuming, from your answer, that it is easier to test - but not that easy. I have to ask though, some classes have to be instantiated only once, like Database class (since instantiating one could be creating another connection resource), what do you think about that?

Comment: @rickchristie: Since I don't know the exact implementation of your code I can't really give you a detailed answer, but there is nothing inherently wrong with using the Singleton lifestyle as long as you understand the constraints. The most important is that if each consumer accesses the shared service from different threads, the service must be thread-safe. This is not a requirement for Transient objects.

Comment: @VJo: I agree that the Singleton pattern is very close to being an anti-pattern, but the difference between the pattern and the lifestyle is that when we are talking about DI and the lifestyle, according to the Liskov Substituion Principle the consumer doesn't know that the provided service is a Singleton. The advantage is not so much in the ability to clean up, but that you prevent Spaghetti code from appearing because there's no global state to pull from.

Comment: @Mark - any resource on DI lifestyles? Can't seem to find any decent one with google.

Comment: I'm not aware of any online resource that collects and contrasts different lifestyles, but FWIW my book has a chapter (8) that is basically a catalog of lifestyles: http://affiliate.manning.com/idevaffiliate.php?id=1150_236

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does introduce a global state, since your factory returns a reference to just created object.

You didn't say which language you are using, but if you are using c++, your factory method should return a shared_ptr (the type for the shared_ptr should be the base class of the object you are creating).

Comment: What about things like Database class? We can't create new database object since it risks creating new connection. In that cases shouldn't every object has a reference to the same Database object? I want to know what you think.

Comment: @rickchristie It all depends. If you don't need to open a new connection, you can create one object, and pass it to all objects which needs a DB connection. This class should have an interface with pure virtual methods, then you can replace this class with a mock.